# Google Analytics item category does not seem to be '/' delimited as promised

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4

After adding Item category and Item category 2 as row dimensions, this is what shows:

[image: "question/competition" under Item category is not delimited to separate columns]

This seems contradictory. How is this possible? Do they need to be capitalized?

I send data in this format:
[image]
Where getAnalytics() returns app.analytics() for a Firebase Application configured to Google Analytics with a Measurement ID.

I'm also trying to make the purchase event work. I know that Analytics is receiving the 'value' property of '[purchase](https://developers.google.com/gtagjs/reference/event#purchase)' but it is not showing up in Conversions. Is there something that needs to be configured? Any feedback helps. Especially from those who have it working.

Comment: show how you send data, pls

Comment: I updated the question to include more information. Let me know if I need to show more.

Answer (score 0):

`item_category` is a string, in GA4 to send other categories you have to use dedicated parameters like `item_category2`, `item_category3`, `item_category4`, `item_category5`: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/10119380?hl=en